# Calculating user time spent using window.beforeunload - window.onload

Tags: javascript

I tried using below simple code to capture user time spent on a page or site from window onload up till window.onbeforeunload() event fires. I am not getting any results.

```
<script>
  var time,timeSite;
  window.onload=function()
  {
   time=new Date();
   window.alert(time);
   //newrelic.setCustomAttribute('test',time);
  }


window.onbeforeunload=function()
{
  timeSite=new Date()-time;
  window.alert(timeSite);
  //window.localStorage['timeSite']=timeSite;
  //newrelic.setCustomAttribute('test2',timeSite);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You've very limited in what you can do in `onbeforeunload`, `alert` is very much not on that list - if not seeing the alert is what you mean by not getting any results, that's why.

Comment: What do you mean, "not getting any results"? No alert box or a blank box or what?

Comment: Not getting any output in alert box/tried output to console and also passed values to newrelic using API, that also didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe alert() does not work well in those functions. But the functions themselves would be getting called. I wrote the times to localStorage, I am able to see the times.